# REACT AWS - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am creating a recipe storing application. I am using REACT fro the front end then am using AWS Api gateway, Lambda and dynamo DB for api call, evocation and storage.
I have managed to get POST, GET and DELETE working but receive a CORS preflight error when I try and perform a PATCH request.

This is the patch method in my lambda and the headers are the same as the ones I am using in my API gateway

```
// Modify a recipe
async function modifyRecipe(recipeId, updateKey, updateValue, docClient) {
  // Log the received payload
  console.log('Received PATCH payload:', { recipeId, updateKey, updateValue });
  console.log('Executing modify...');

  if (updateValue !== undefined) {
    // Construct parameters for DynamoDB update
    const params = {
      TableName: dynamodbTableName,
      Key: { 'recipeId': recipeId },
      UpdateExpression: `set ${updateKey} = :value`,
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':value': updateValue,
      },
      ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
    };

    try {
      // Log the parameters and attempt to execute the update
      console.log('UpdateItem parameters:', params);
      const response = await docClient.send(new UpdateCommand(params));
      console.log('UpdateItem operation successful:', response);

      // If successful, return a success response
      const successResponse = buildResponse(200, { message: 'Update successful', 

      // Set CORS headers directly in the response object
      successResponse.headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5173',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      };

      return successResponse;

    } catch (error) {
      // If an error occurs during the update, log the error and return an error response
      console.error('Error updating item:', error);
      console.log("Invoked by error");

      // Return an error response with CORS headers directly in the response object
      return {
        ...buildResponse(500, { error: 'Internal Server Error' }),
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5173',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        },
      };
    }
  } else {
    // If updateValue is undefined, return a bad request response
    console.log('Update value is undefined. Skipping the update operation.');

    // Return a bad request response with CORS headers
    return {
      ...buildResponse(400, {
        error: 'Bad Request',
        message: 'Update value is undefined',
      }),
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5173',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      },
    };
  }
}
```

I have matched the headers in my lambda function to the headers in my API gateway for the OPTIONS  integration response